# Non-zero fill centerpoint for highcharts/highstock?

Tags: highcharts, gwt-highcharts

I have searched for answers to this using various combinations of the following search terms, with no results to speak of: highcharts, highstock, area, centerpoint, zero, center.

I am simply wondering if, when configuring an area-chart, it is possible to change the point around which the plot's fill is centered.  By default, charts fill from zero to the data-line, but there are situations where a user may wish to see how their plot varies around a non-zero base-line.

Is there a way to accomplish this in the highcharts/highstock API?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are just talking about the y axis min:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.min

If that doesn't do what you are asking for, then perhaps threshold will:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.threshold

Comment: Yes, I think that threshold is what I am looking for...  I will try that out and see if that's it!  Thanks for the assistance!